¿Como obtener en los Forms de la app del mismo Theme actual del sistema?
Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion con Visual Studio (Community 2022), basada en un formato de Aplicación WPF.
Eatoy programando los temas de estilo de paletas de colores de la aplicación, y me ocurre que las barras de títulos de las ventanas no cambian del color blanco, al cambiar el sistema a Modo oscuro.

He buscado información sobre este asunto por la red, pero, aunque encontré una buena respuesta, no era para este tipo de formato de proyectos (WPF), sino para UWP.
También comentar, que este proyecto no usa de ningun modo XAML sino un modo de interfaz vectorial (por las dudas).
¿Alguien sabría como puedo cambiar el color de la barra de titulos, o desbloquear su tema, o quitar el tema claro que parece venir configurado de modo fijo por defecto en las apps WPF .NET en C# para que siga al tema actual del sistema?
....
He estado leyendo, escribiendo con los enlaces que me han compartido y os agradezco, en un comentario aquí abajo.
Llega un punto en que debo añadir o acceder al codigo XAML de las ventanas.
En principio nunca manejo esto (XAML), y en mi solución, no tengo ni encuentro por ninguna parte código de marcado ninguno de parte alguna de la app.
Yo utilizo un encabezado que os comparto a continuación para utilizar Forms en modo vectorial, y de ahi trabajar a parte por cuenta propia el asunto responsive y el resto de lo que necesite la interfaz.
public partial class Form1: Form
public class App:System.Windows.Application
{
Form1 unForm1;
  
  public void App_ini(Form1 _unForm1)
  {
  _unForm1.AllowTransparency= true;
  unForm1 = _unForm1;
  return;
  }
}
public Form1()
{
App x= new App();
x.App_ini(this);
SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedBuffer,true);
InitalizeComponent();
...
...
} ...

Y no logro por mas que lo intento y lo busco, abrir el ViewDesigner, ni ninguna hoja de marcado de XAML. Yo se que jamás programo ni uso eso, por esto os lo comentaba anteriormente, mas bien rehuyo de usar XAML, y mi forma de enfocar los proyectos es justo evitar por ejemplo usar interfaz de ese tipo.
Creo, aunque no lo se seguro, que al utilizar ese encabezado que utilizo para hacer vectorial los proyectos de este tipo y usar esto de base para desarrollar por cuenta ajena la interfaz de la app, puede tener que ver con que no este disponible precisamente las plantillas de marcado XAML de ventanas ni controles en mis proyectos WPF.
Un cordial saludo, Sergio

me tenes confundido.. o es wpf o es winforms.. las dos cosas al mismo tiempo no es...

Ah, ok. Pues, es un proyecto tipo WPF .NET Desktop. Ya lo he editado para aclarar la consulta.

Pues, es un proyecto tipo WPF .NET Desktop esto tiene dudas ... es o no es WPF???

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/styles-templates-overview?view=netdesktop-8.0

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72672788/how-create-dynamic-themes-in-wpf-applications

Si. Es un protecto de aplicación de escritorio .NET de tipo WPF. Aparte de esto, lleva un encabezado justo antes de la inicializacion de componenentes al comienzo, que hereda de App : System.Windows.Application lo cual parece cambiar el comportamiento del IDE en cuanto a la interfaz, he tratado de agregar esta información en la consulta.

Ok, he encontrado la solucion.
Le importo esta .dll para invokar lo siguiente:
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = false)]
public static extern void DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, 
                                                DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE attribute, 
                                                ref int pvAttribute, 
                                                uint cbAttribute); 

También le añado esta enumeración:
public enum DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE : uint
{
    DWMWA_NCRENDERING_ENABLED,
    DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY,
    DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED,
    DWMWA_ALLOW_NCPAINT,
    DWMWA_CAPTION_BUTTON_BOUNDS,
    DWMWA_NONCLIENT_RTL_LAYOUT,
    DWMWA_FORCE_ICONIC_REPRESENTATION,
    DWMWA_FLIP3D_POLICY,
    DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS,
    DWMWA_HAS_ICONIC_BITMAP,
    DWMWA_DISALLOW_PEEK,
    DWMWA_EXCLUDED_FROM_PEEK,
    DWMWA_CLOAK,
    DWMWA_CLOAKED,
    DWMWA_FREEZE_REPRESENTATION,
    DWMWA_PASSIVE_UPDATE_MODE,
    DWMWA_USE_HOSTBACKDROPBRUSH,
    DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE = 20,
    DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE = 33,
    DWMWA_BORDER_COLOR,
    DWMWA_CAPTION_COLOR,
    DWMWA_TEXT_COLOR,     
    DWMWA_VISIBLE_FRAME_BORDER_THICKNESS,
    DWMWA_SYSTEMBACKDROP_TYPE,
    DWMWA_LAST
}

Y para terminar le añado este código a la altura de la inicialización de componentes del Form:
var preference = Convert.ToInt32(true);
DwmSetWindowAttribute(this.Handle,DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE.DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE,ref preference, sizeof(uint));


Y arreglado para la barra de titulos con el Modo Oscuro.
